# How to return the average from a file in Python?

Tags: python, list, file

This should return the average of all of the values in the file. This is what I have. I get an error, could anyone help me out? Thank you!

```
    def averageValueOnFile(fileName):
        with open('fileName.txt') as f:
             sum=0
             count=0
             for line in f:
                 count+=1
                 sum+=float(line.split(":")[1])
             average=sum/count
        print (average)

    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What's the input file look like?

Comment: And python didn't give you a full stack frame including the line with the error? That's strange. It usually does.

Comment: Consider a file with a blank line at the end.... `line.split(":")` would not give you two items. You may want to check for empty lines before the split.

Answer (score 2):

What do the contents of the file look like?

One or more of your lines in the file does not have a : or is simply blank after the colon

Would `sum+=float(line.split(":")[0])` work instead?

Comment: It did, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your error likely comes from the fact that one of the lines in the file is not formatted as you expect: the `split` method returns a list with less than two elements.